# Can field() be requested in a QWizard before initialization?

Tags: c++, qt, field, wizard

I am calling a QWizardPage from a function in the MainWindow

```
void MainWindow::NoiseFilling()
{
    QWizard *wiz = new QWizard;
    NoiseFillPage *pg = new NoiseFillPage(&data);
    wiz->addPage(pg);
    wiz->setWindowTitle("Noise Filling");
    wiz->setOption(QWizard::NoBackButtonOnStartPage);

    QVBoxLayout *ly = new QVBoxLayout;
    QLabel *pb = new QLabel;
    ly->addWidget(wiz);
    ly->addWidget(pb);

    connect(wiz,&QDialog::accepted,[&](){data.NoiseFill(wiz->field("percent").toInt(),wiz->field("factor").toString());});
    connect(wiz,&QDialog::accepted,[&](){textEdit->setText("Dataset noise filled.\n");});
    delete frame->layout();   // delete previous layout
    frame->setLayout(ly);
    wiz->show();
}
```

and the constructor of the WizardPage looks like that

```
NoiseFillPage::NoiseFillPage(DataFrame* df,QWidget* parent)
    : QWizardPage(parent)
{
    box = new QComboBox;
    lab = new QLabel("Metadata factor");
    lab_2 = new QLabel("% of missing values threshold to fill");
    sb = new QSpinBox;

    box->insertItem(0,*(df->className));
    box->insertItems(1,*(df->namesMetaData));

    sb->setMaximum(100);
    sb->setMinimum(30);
    sb->setValue(100);

    QGridLayout *ly = new QGridLayout;
    ly->addWidget(box,0,0);
    ly->addWidget(lab,0,1);
    ly->addWidget(sb,1,0);
    ly->addWidget(lab_2,1,1);

    setLayout(ly);

    registerField("factor",box);
    registerField("percent",sb);
}
```

I receive a segmentation fault when I accept (and therefore close) the dialog of the one-page wizard. The debugger stops on the `connect` instruction making me believe that the problem arises because I am requesting two fields which are not initialised in compile-time. It is also true that this connection would be made at run time so I am very confused. Does anybody have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: What if remove `delete frame->layout();` ?

Comment: I need that line to remove the previous layout. Anyway I encounter the same problem even removing that line.

Comment: Qt manage QObject derives memory by it self, if you set proper parent during construction, so setLayout should be enough, may be this `delete` cause `double free error`

Comment: It does not, I have tested it. The problem is not there.

Comment: where does `data` come from? could it be that it becomes invalid after the function call? It's not the connect that failes, but something inside the lambda function.

Comment: `data` is an object of a class called `Dataframe` which has several pointers to `QStringList`s as attributes (like `className` and `namesMetaData`) and a numerical matrix implemented through `armadillo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was capturing by reference a local variable (`wiz`) in the lambda function which caused undefined behaviour even though the variable was still in scope when the lambda executed.